# Can I test a Twilio Fax listening page without sending a fax

Tags: twilio, fax

Is there a way to test my Twilio fax listening page without sending a fax? I want to see what data would come in to the listening page.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could test the full flow by sending a fax from your Twilio number to your Twilio number. That way you don't need to get hold of a fax machine.

Once you've done that once, you could record the requests and replay them to test again.